lightgbmでランキング学習をしていますが、いつまでたってもモデル学習が終わりません。パラメータの設定等に問題があるのでしょうか？
競馬予想でlightgbmのランキング学習をしています。特徴量の処理などを全部やった後で、モデル学習に移るんですが、モデル学習が何時間かかっても終わりません。パラメータの設定の問題でしょうか？　ご指導のほどよろしくお願いいたします。
windows11 メモリ128kb ストレージ3Tb　ハード的には十分だと思うのですが。
# データとラベルを訓練データと検証データに分割
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(df, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# LightGBM のデータセット形式に変換
train_data = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train, group=group, categorical_feature=categorical_features)
validation_data = lgb.Dataset(X_valid, label=y_valid)

# パラメータの設定
import lightgbm as lgb

# パラメータの設定
params = {
    'objective': 'lambdarank',
    'metric': 'ndcg',
    'learning_rate': 0.05,
    'num_leaves': 31,
    'verbose': 1
}

# モデルの学習
gbm = lgb.train(
    params,
    train_data,
    num_boost_round=1000,
    valid_sets=[validation_data],
    callbacks=[lgb.callback.print_evaluation(period=1)]
)


もしかするとこちらの記事を利用しているが上手くいかないということですか？ LightGBMによるAI競馬予想(ランキング学習) そこには冒頭にこの記事を読む前に「LightGBMによるAI競馬予想(準備編)」の記事を先に読んでください。その中には、機械学習の基礎知識や、学習データで使う説明変数の内容など、他のデータ分析方法と共通する説明が含まれています。とありますが、そちらを参考に調べてみてはどうでしょう？ LightGBMによるAI競馬予想(準備編) そうでなければ、例えばJupyterLab/Notebookで作っていて該当箇所のセルだけ提示されているような感じですが、他の人が試せる完全な形で提示してみてください。再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方

コメントありがとうございます。いろんな書き方があるようで、この書き方でもできると思うので、何が悪いのかわからないので質問しております。

改善の問いかけに対して思いを返されても質問の内容が詳細化されるとかでなければ更なる助言や回答が出てくる可能性は上がらないと思われます。何をしようとして何が起こっていてそれの何処が問題なのかといった情報が他の人でも分かりやすいように追記されると助言・回答が付きやすいでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考にしてください。良い質問をするには？

「windows11 メモリ128kb ストレージ3Tb　ハード的には十分だと思うのですが。」とありますが、メモリ128kbではなくメモリ128GBですか？ 実際のメモリの使用状況はどうなっていましたか？ また、学習自体は進んでいるのでしょうか？

コメントありがとうございます。128GBの間違いでした。メモリは15.889.2MB（20％程度）使用されています。エラーが出るのではなく、4時間学習を続けても終わらないという状況です。

「128GBの間違いでした。」については質問を修正しましょう。コメント欄は回答者の目に留まりにくいです。また、学習自体は進んでいるのでしょうか？

またどういう内容のモデルなのかを簡単に説明すると回答者が回答しやすくなるかと思います。
